# Why does assigning a single to a variant result in a varDouble variant?

Tags: delphi, variant

```
uses
  SysUtils, Variants;

var
  VariantSingle: Variant;
  VTSingle: TVarType;
  SingleTest: Single;
  VariantDouble: Variant;
  DoubleTest: Double;
  VTDouble: TVarType;

begin
  SingleTest := 1.234;
  VariantSingle := SingleTest;
  VTSingle := VarType(VariantSingle) and varTypeMask;

  DoubleTest := 1.23456;
  VariantDouble := DoubleTest;
  VTDouble := VarType(VariantDouble) and varTypeMask;

  WriteLn(Format('VarType: Single: %d, Double %d', [VTSingle, VTDouble]));
end.
```

The code above will output:

> VarType: Single: 5, Double 5

From System.pas

```
varSingle   = $0004; { vt_r4           4 }
varDouble   = $0005; { vt_r8           5 }
```

Thus, I'd expect VTSingle to be **4** - not 5 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi libraries choose to implement all floating point assignments to variants by means of a call to `_VarFromReal`. And that function looks like this:

```
procedure _VarFromReal(var V: TVarData; const Value: Real);
begin
  if (V.VType and varDeepData) <> 0 then
    VarClearDeep(V);
  V.VType := varDouble;
  V.VDouble := Value;
end;
```

Note that this uses a type of `varDouble`. And includes an implicit conversion to `Real` which is an alias for `Double`. I'm not sure why the designers chose that particular route, but the consequence of that choice is the behaviour that you observe.

A simple way to make a `varSingle` variant you can use:

```
VariantSingle := VarAsType(SingleTest, varSingle);
```

Although this will convert `SingleTest` to `Double`, and then back again to `Single`.

To avoid that needless conversion, write your own helper:

```
function VarFromSingle(const Value: Single): Variant;
begin
  VarClear(Result);
  TVarData(Result).VSingle := Value;
  TVarData(Result).VType := varSingle;
end;
```

which you can call like this:

```
VariantSingle := VarFromSingle(SingleTest);
```

This latter approach is the correct solution in my opinion.

Comment: Did you translate the `_VarFromReal` procedure from asm to Pascal? At least in Delphi 2009, it is implemented as a `asm` procedure.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Modern Delphis also have Pascal versions for the benefit of the new non x86 targets. So I used the Pascal version here.