# How do I call functions that receive floating point values using IDispatch.Invoke?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm having trouble calling a function that has a floating point argument and a floating point result, using `IDispatch.Invoke`.

Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <comutil.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CComPtr<IDispatch> wordapp;
    if (SUCCEEDED(wordapp.CoCreateInstance(L"Word.Application", NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)))
    {
        CComVariant result;
        CComVariant centimeters((float)2.0);
        CComVariant retval = wordapp.Invoke1(L"CentimetersToPoints", &centimeters, &result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the ATL `CComPtr` to make things cleaner. But it's a very loose wrapper around `IDispatch.Invoke`.

When I run this, the call to `Invoke1` fails and returns `E_FAIL`.

I suspect that the problem is related to the use of floating point arguments and/or return value. If I call a function that does not use such values, the invoke succeeds:

```
CComVariant retval = wordapp.Invoke0(L"ProductCode", &result);
```

I note that if I call the function from VBS, or from PowerShell, it succeeds. I'm presuming that they both use late bound `IDispatch` and so that would indicate that what I am attempting is at least possible.

So, how can I call this function using `IDispatch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that was a head-scratcher.  The documentation for this "method" is very misleading, it is not a method.  It behaves more like an indexed property and requires the DISPATCH_METHOD | DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET flags.  CComPtr doesn't support that, you'll need to spin this by hand.  This code worked:

```
    CComVariant result;
    CComVariant centimeters((float)2.0);
    DISPID dispid;
    LPOLESTR name = L"CentimetersToPoints";
    HRESULT hr = wordapp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispid);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    DISPPARAMS dispparams = { &centimeters, NULL, 1, 0};
    hr = wordapp->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_METHOD | DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dispparams, &result, nullptr, nullptr);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

Comment: It probably should not be in documentation, it should be in some generic observations instead. Look here please: http://pastebin.ca/2369858 It seems that Delphi RTL adds get-property flag for every method with return value and zero arguments. Most obvious solution would be wiping the arg-count check and ALWAYS converting method-with-return to method+prop-getter, but i cannot predict the larger consequences of that, may it break some other method calls that would ONLY work without prop-getter flag?

Comment: *Some languages cannot distinguish between retrieving a property and calling a method. In this case, you should set the flags DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET and DISPATCH_METHOD.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221486.aspx  Does it mean that Method-or-getter is always a safe fall-back and extra "ArgCount == 0" guard should be considered a bug in Delphi RTL ? @DavidHeffernan : QC-able ?